# php echo result line by line in mail

Tags: php, email

Hi i am using php script to send mails and at the i use echo to display results. i am running this script through cron which is sending me the output. but result is not line by line i have tried `\r\n` but still not working code is

```
$emailBody= chunk_split(base64_encode($emailBody));
$headers = "From: Lotus ERP Attendance <erp@lotus.edu.in>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: erp@lotus.edu.in\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: erp@lotus.edu.in\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";

      if(mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {
          echo 'Success:';
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['enroll_no'];
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['First_Name'];
          echo ' ';
          echo $row['Last_Name'];
          echo '-----';
          echo 'Email sent successfully!\r\n';
      } else {
      }

}
else {
          echo 'Failure:';
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['enroll_no'];
          echo '-----';
          echo $row['First_Name'];
          echo ' ';
          echo $row['Last_Name'];
          echo '-----';
          echo 'Failure: Email was not sent!\r\n';
      }
```

result which i am getting on my mail is this

```
/usr/lib/php/modules/xcache.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
Success:-----1103106-----HARI SINGH-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103107-----MUNENDRA KUMAR-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103110-----TARUN UPADHYAY-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103111-----SHUBHAM SAXENA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103112-----SANA JAHAN-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103122-----SAIF WASEEM-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103124-----AMIR KHAN(A)-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103126-----HINA ZAHRA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103127-----AMAN KUMAR KASHYAP-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103128-----MADAN SINGH MEHTA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103129-----PRIYAMVADA MISHRA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103133-----HITESH KUMAR PAHWA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103134-----FAIZ AHMAD-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103135-----ABDUL SAMAD-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103137-----SHEFALI AGARWAL-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103139-----JITENDRA MISHRA-----Email sent successfully!\r\nSuccess:-----1103155-----ZAFAR .-----Email sent successfully!\r\n
```

i want this line by line and what about this error `/usr/lib/php/modules/xcache.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension`

Comment: add `header("Content-type: text/plain");` on top to get plain text output.

Comment: if i will do this then then formatting of mails which is being sent by this script will disturb.

Comment: Why don't you use a library to send an email like PHPMailer? `mail()` funciton is not the best way to send emails out.

Comment: @user3210029 why on earth header of the current script would affect email formating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the \n inside " not ', and try again. I think it is the right way.

`echo "whatever \n";`

Comment: what about this error `/usr/lib/php/modules/xcache.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension`